# One step or two step mail validation using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Please, some clarifications:
Till now I used two steps validations (client/server) for some user inputs, for example - email (classic form submitting - by reloading the page).

If I use php-jquery ajax method - is it clever all the validation perform on server (because application already communicates with the server), or maybe keep some validations on the client side too.

Second, is there a better way for php mail validation than the following:

```
If(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))...
```

And finally, is there any language, any framework, any... whatever (for web development) where all variables, once declared, are automatically available everywhere, on each page, on each file inside the project ?

Comment: You have three questions that are unrelated (or at best, tangentially related). You should ask them seperately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server Side/Client Side or Both User Input Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852287/server-side-client-side-or-both-user-input-validation)

Comment: @Quentin, no problem to delete this part, but it requires just yes or no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember:

> Always let the final validation to the server

If you use Php/Ajax form handler you should validate the input at the very first submit from the user and than you send a response (202 or 0) based on the validation success.

For the email verification, after the users send all the data and the form is complete, you can send to him a token (via Email) that let him to "activate" the account 
Something like http://www.myFakesite.com/activate.php?tkref=2423fuhr334hu (unique for every users of course)

Last the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` it's a great validator but it doesn't check the DNS records

Comment: Claudio, is it ok if `the final validation` is `the only validation performed` if I use php ajax ?

Comment: Yes because if you send and Email to the user, and he use a fake email, you never flag that user as "Checked" or activate or whatever you want XD